# Constant variable names in all modules/functions

Tags: python-3.x, variables, constants

This is version 2 of my question, after the comment on v1 by Omer Dagry.

What's the best way to ensure that constants are available throughout my code?

I've created this constants.ini file that I want to be able to use in any module I create to ensure standard variables for certain functions.

```
; dd_config.ini
    [DEBUG_TYPE]
    DEBUG_SUBSTR = -1
    DEBUG_START = 0
    DEBUG_OS = 1
    DEBUG_GENERAL = 2
    DEBUG_END = 3
```

I have re-ordered program 1 so that it populates dd_con before importing dd_debug_exception:

```python
from configparser import ConfigParser
# read the .ini file for some of the code
dd_con = ConfigParser()
dd_con.read(
    "C:/Users/DD/dd_constants.ini"
    )
# standard error reporting if debug needed
from test_debug_2 import dd_debug_exception

_SHORT = dd_con.get("DEBUG_STYLE", "DEBUG_SHORT")

print(_SHORT)

dd_debug_exception(0, "test", _SHORT)
```

Import dd_debug_exception does this:

```python
def dd_debug_exception(debug_type,
                       debug_str,
                       debug_style: int = dd_con.get("DEBUG_TYPE",
                                "DEBUG_NORMAL")):
    # Handle exceptions in a standard way

    if debug_style == _SHORT:
        print("hello")
```

When I try to run it I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\DD\test_config.py", line 9, in 
> from test_debug_2 import dd_debug_exception   File "C:\Users\DD\test_debug_2.py", line 3, in 
> debug_style: int = dd_con.get("DEBUG_TYPE", NameError: name 'dd_con' is not defined

The import is still not recognising dd_con and therefore my standard variables.

Comment: you import `dd_debug_exception` before declaring `dd_con` and the default value of the parameter `debug_style` of `dd_debug_exception` is `dd_con.get("DEBUG_TYPE", "DEBUG_NORMAL")`

Comment: Thanks @OmerDagry. I've revised my code but am still not getting the result I want.

Comment: what error are you getting now?

Comment: As noted in the question:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\DD\test_config.py", line 9, in from test_debug_2 import dd_debug_exception File "C:\Users\DD\test_debug_2.py", line 3, in debug_style: int = dd_con.get("DEBUG_TYPE", NameError: name 'dd_con' is not defined

Comment: but it's the same error, you didn't `declare` `dd_con` **in the imported module**

Comment: you can't declare a variable in one file and import another file that uses that variable as default, you delete the default value and pass `dd_con` every time you call the function `dd_debug_exception`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `declare` `dd_con` in `dd_debug_exception`?  I've tried a number of variants to try this but none of them work.

Hopefully I won't have to pass `dd_con` as an argument to the `dd_debug_exception`  function because that won't give me what I'm looking for :(

Comment: unless you can create `dd_con` in the same file the `dd_debug_exception` function is imported from, you do need to pass `dd_con` as an argument to the `dd_debug_exception` function

Comment: OK thanks. I'll find another way!!